# ionic 3 angular 5 restapi request not working

Tags: json, typescript, api, ionic3, angular5

I'm trying to get data from a api but I cannot print the values in the app. doesn't read the json correctly. not sure what I did wrong..any help for would be helpful. I need to be able to parse down in the json to get the strat_name

this is my code

home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestApiProvider } from '../../providers/restapi/restapi';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    names: string[];
    errorMessage: string;
    descending: boolean = false;
    order: number;
    column: string = 'name';

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public rest: RestApiProvider) { }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.getNames();
    }

    getNames() {
        this.rest.getNames()
            .subscribe(
                names => this.names = names,
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }


    sort() {
        this.descending = !this.descending;
        this.order = this.descending ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Name List
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="terms"></ion-searchbar>
  <button ion-button type="button" (click)="sort()">Sort</button>
    <h1>{{names | json}}</h1>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let c of names | search : terms | sort: {property: column, order: order}">
    <h2>{{c.strat_name}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

restapi:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class RestApiProvider {

    private apiUrl = 'https://macrostrat.org/api/v2/defs/strat_names?all';

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log(this.apiUrl);
    }

    getNames(): Observable<string[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(
            map(this.extractData),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res;
        return body || {};
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const err = error || '';
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

}
```

not sure what I did wrong..any help for would be helpful. I need to be able to parse down in the json to get the strat_names.

[first, it loads the json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymkk4.png)

[once I click on search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps5t0.png)

Comment: Hi! do you get some error? could you log the response from the server and the content of names after the api responds in home.ts?

Comment: would you please add this in your html (right after sort button) and share the result `{{names | json}}`

Comment: is this correct? <button ion-button type="button" (click)="sort()">Sort</button> {{names | json}} so I when I do that I get items.filer is not a function @RezaRahmati

Comment: json pipe just displays your object as json in your html, so it wouldn't cause that issue, but also it means there is an issue in your code, so for track it down please remove `| search : terms | sort: {property: column, order: order}` from your `ion-item`

Comment: @RezaRahmati now I get a error trying to diff' '{Object Object}'. only arrays and  iterables are allowed

Comment: OK, please do this, go to stackblitz.com and create a project there try to reproduce the issue and share the link here, so we can directly help you there

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mm56rn @RezaRahmati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issue in your code

1.Your data is coming like `{ success : { data : array} }` so to access data you need to do below

```
  private extractData(res: any) {
    if (res && res.success && res.success.data) {
      return res.success.data;
    }
    return [];
  }
```

2.In your html you need to access the properties like this

```
  <ion-item *ngFor="let n of names">
    <h2>{{n?.strat_name}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
```

3.Your data is too much and cause a lot of delays to show the data

After all of that fixes it will look like below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jb6ni9

[image]

Comment: thank you! does the delay make the search bar not work? @RezaRahmati

Comment: Lbook, you need ti implement search and sort, btw angular is strongly avoiding us to have search and sort pipe.

Btw if this answer solved your issue you can upvote my answer and mark it as answer